# CS1501: No overload for method 'btnsaveandclose_Click' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hi I am getting this error when i try to run 
aspx.cs is

```
protected void btnsaveandclose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

aspx is:

```
<asp:button id="btnsaveandclose" runat="server" text="save & close" 
     CausesValidation="true" onclick="btnsaveandclose_Click()" 
     usesubmitbehavior="false">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `onclick` is trying to call the function there and then (and without the requisite arguments):

```
onclick="btnsaveandclose_Click()"
```

Should be:

```
onclick="btnsaveandclose_Click"
```

You just need to use the *name* of the event handler, not call it.

Answer (score 2):

remove the brackets in your `onclick=btnsaveandclose_Click()`

Comment: `Parenthesis` you mean these are `Braces {}`

Comment: @DJKRAZE, yes and no. Across various English dialects "parentheses" and "brackets" are used interchangably